# php artisan serve on local network

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a project in laravel and to test the site on mobile i have been running the following command:

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.83.1 --port 8000
```

This used to work fine, and still does on my own laptop.
However it suddenly stopped working on my phone and i can't seem to figure out why.
Could their be changes i have made to my laptop that are blocking the route?
Or have i changed something in my project which does not allow for mobile devices?

Comment: is the page not found or site not found. which error occurs?

Comment: The website does respond, and is giving an ERR_TIMED_OUT

Comment: clear the cache, route and view of laravel project and re-run.

Comment: Do i clear the cache route and view on my mobile device or is there a cache in my laravel project i haven't heard about

Comment: Yes there is cache created by laravel. clear by hitting "php artisan cache:clear" command and clear the views by hitting "php artisan view:clear"

Comment: Have you checked if your local IP address has changed?

Comment: Silly question but, is your mobile on the same network as your laptop?

Comment: I have checked my ip adres, i've updated that my laptop is connected (wired) to the same network as my mobile device (wifi)

Comment: clearing the cache and views sadly did not work

Comment: turns out i'm incapable of reading my ipconfig, i was using the wrong ip adres

Comment: check your ip adress and try to disable any firewall in your laptop ...